# In a python docker containerized app, how do I collect user command line input

Tags: python, docker

In my simple app that ask user for an input, I am not able to interact with the input() function before the app closes. Is there a proper way to do this for Docker containerized apps?

after running the excerpt below with docker run the command prompt closes before collecting user input.

x = input("What is your name)"
print (x)

Comment: Try passing `-it` like `docker run -it my-image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the command `docker run -i -t <your-options>`

Here, `-i` will keep STDIN open and `-t` will allocate a pseudo terminal on which you will be able to enter the value you want like any commandline application.